# Not able to play H265 stream with DRM on chrome

Tags: drm, hevc, hls.js, shaka, dash.js

Integrated shaka-player for `HEVC/H.265` and `drm` encrypted videos which works fine on safari but on chrome video is not playing(**HEVC/H.265 when DRM encrypted**)

I can check in https://caniuse.com/?search=hevc there is support for HEVC/H.265 in chrome but don't why it is not supported with DRM
Also raised this issue with shaka-player team https://github.com/shaka-project/shaka-player/issues/5540

Is there any alternative of shaka-player or any other way we can run HEVC/H.265 content with DRM which supports all browser

Anyone who worked with HEVC/H.265 please provide your input best way to integrate it on web with DRM any input would be of great help

I also tried with dashjs and hls.js but same issue exists

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Shaka Player issue. Chrome recently added H.265 playback support, but it doesn't yet work with Widevine. No video library is going to give you that capability, because it's intrinsic to the browser, the operating system and the underlying hardware.